# Monitoring Rancher containers by hosts through Prometheus cAdvisor NodeExporter

Tags: grafana, prometheus, rancher, cadvisor, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a setup where I manage to monitor every container of my Rancher 1.6 environnement with a stack Prometheus(2.4.3)/Grafana (with cAdvisor v0.27.4 and NodeExporter v0.16.0).

Here is my issue. I manage to monitor every container consumption but I can't relate the consumption of a container based on the host.

For example, if I want to show information about CPU usage I use container_cpu_user_seconds_total from cAdvisor which provides cpu usage of the container in percentage related to its host but I can't find which host is concerned (I Have 4 hosts on this environnement) so the cpu consumption cumulative tends to go over 100%.

I would like to either show charts by host (I saw I could create dynamic charts in Grafana but it seems a bit hard so manually creating them doesn't bother me).

Should I try to create my own metrics in prom-conf file ? Seems a bit overkill for such stuff

I find this very strange that this information only interests me. That's why I ask it here.

I'm new to all of these tools.

Thank you in advance.